# Can I use a dynamic model in variable settings?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-model

I have this code

```
 $this->loadModel($model);
 $this->Task->id = $id;
 $this->Task->save($this->data[$model]);
```

How can I setup the "Task" model so I can make it dynamic because this doesn't work:

```
 $this->loadModel($model);
 $this->$model->id = $id;
 $this->$model->save($this->data[$model]);
```

I also tried this with no luck:

```
 $this->loadModel($model);
 $this->currentModel = $model;
 $this->currentModel->id = $id;
 $this->currentModel->save($this->data[$model]);
```

Comment: "doesn't work" what do you mean? what exactly happens? the middle version should work IMO.

Comment: What's the value of $model?

Comment: var_dump($aux = $this->loadModel($model));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one...

```
<?php

// THE DYNAMIC MODEL
App::Import('Model', $model);
$this->DynamicModel = new $model;

// USAGE EXAMPLE

function getModelColumns($model){
App::Import('Model', $model);
$this->DynamicModel = new $model;
print_r($this->DynamicModel->getColumnTypes());exit();
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at http://grahamwideman.wordpress.com/2009/08/05/php-grammar-notes/

You can wrap local variables in curly braces to evaluate the variable.

```
$this->{$model}->id = $id;
```